# Doing Empirical Orthogonal Function (EOF) analysis in R

Tags: r, pca

I am very new to R and statistics as a whole so this may be a very simple question. I am trying to carry out [empirical orthogonal function (EOF) analysis](https://climatedataguide.ucar.edu/climate-data-tools-and-analysis/empirical-orthogonal-function-eof-analysis-and-rotated-eof-analysis) of sea-level pressure (SLP) data to determine the amplitude of the North Atlantic Oscillation over time.

I have a matrix (1000,756), with 1000 years of winter mean SLP (i.e. from December to March) at 756 grid points in the North Atlantic.

How do I go about doing an EOF analysis on this data?

I have spent the last week trying to do a crash course in R but am a little tight for time so I thought I would ask! Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please define "EOF".

Comment: Hi Roland, an Empirical Orthogonal Function is essentially a Principle component analysis. The literature is very unclear and often uses the two terms (EOF/PCA) interchangeably. One definition is "the EOF method finds both time series and spatial patterns".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

R has routines for doing PCA (`prcomp` is the preferred method), and also SVD (`svd`)`*`, which are the bases for EOF. It also has a `screeplot` and other tools, but I'm not sure how much code you'll have to put around the SVD itself to do what you want.

There is a [`spacetime`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spacetime) package that has a function `EOF`. On github there is the [`sinkr`](https://github.com/marchtaylor/sinkr) package with an EOF function. At one point, there was a clim.pact package in R, which features an EOF function, but it has been removed from CRAN (perhaps because no longer maintained).

EDIT: You may find answers to a [similar question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28996/principal-component-analysis-in-r) useful.

EDIT 2: There are also at least three versions of "EOF": EOF, REOF (Rotated EOF), and EEOF (Extended EOF, to include time correlations). At least according to one page I saw online, which might be outdated and perhaps EOF always refers to EEOF now-a-days. Do you know what version you want to use?

`*` The prcmp documentation mentions it does an SVD under the hood, so these two options are not totally distinct.

Comment: Hi Wayne, thank you for your answer. According to the literature I need to do plain EOF analysis. As there is no longer an EOF function in R I have done the standard princomp.

Comment: @EdwardArmstrong: R has a `princomp` which is mainly for compatability with its predecessor language S. The preferred function to use is `prcomp`, which uses SVD. It mentions this if you get help on princomp: `?princomp`.